# Removing only the third instance of a - from a given field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a supposed date field but the data is coming in as a nvarchar in the form `27-01-2023 - 15:18:52`. It appears that extra `-` is causing SQL Server not to recognize it as a date and means I can't use the CAST function without it throwing an error.

Normally I would use REPLACE to change it to a blank then use cast but that obviously affects all the -'s in the field which messes up the date portion. How do I go about telling SQL to remove the 3rd instance of a - from this field?

Comment: replace `' - '` with a blank.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: *Normally I would use REPLACE* - yes that's what you need here also.

Comment: "with a supposed date field but the data is coming in as a nvarchar" -> This is your main problem. Yes, you can write a query with a replace, but this is risky, unhandy and can produce unintended results depending on your data. Do not store anything "similar to a date" in a varchar column. If you want to store dates, store them as date with correct format in a date column. A varchar column should be used only for texts etc., not for dates with an incorrect dash.

Comment: If your application or whatever produces this incorrect dash within your "date", fix this issue to create a real, correct date, alter your column to date and save that date there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to combine REPLACE and `CONVERT` function, which could specify DateTime format style (103 is corresponding of dd/MM/yyyy, British/French standard date format).

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE('27-01-2023 - 15:18:52', ' - ', ' '), 103)
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RmjrCPCV)